# Why does Resharper add "@" to enum?

Tags: c#, resharper-9.0

Hi I am using Resharper 9 and I encountered
this situation: I write

```
public enum EnumExample
{
   var1,
   var2
}
something = EnumExample.var1;
```

and Resharper wants me to change it to

```
public enum EnumExample
{
   var1,
   var2
}
something = EnumExample.@var1;
```

Can someone explain why and what is the difference? Code compiles in both situation correctly.

EDIT: I edit example to be more clear.

Comment: Resharper is just making the code clearer by explicitly calling out the in this case `Enum` is an identifier and not a type.

Comment: Just change the settings for that in ReSharper. The `@` ensures that the next word isn't taken as a keyword but as an identifier, in short.

Comment: `Enum` is not a keyword but a (built in) Type. The `@` is a little overzealous here. Resharper needed some attention. For reference, list the number or the exact text from the warning that appears without the symbol.

Comment: Can't reproduce this (RS #9.2) and the provided code is invalid.

Comment: I know, that provided code is not valid It is for example (unfortunate one, i change it to be more clear). It shows on resharper 9.1